# What do these random-looking repository names mean in Docker?

Tags: image, docker

maybe this is a duplicate but I couldn't find any reference for this.

I don't understand what are this images that I see in the output of `docker images ls`. In the `repository` column I see some images with a hash in their names.

[image: docker image ls]

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out where the images come from, they are built by Jenkins.

Answer (score 0):

If you're iterating on a custom image, when you `docker build -t imagename .`, the `imagename:latest` tag moves to the newly built image, and the previous image is left behind with just a hash and no other name.  You can assign a name to the old image with `docker tag`, or delete it with `docker rmi`.

If you are on Docker 1.13 or newer (including any date-format version like 2017.12) then you can [ask Docker to clean up the untagged images](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/image_prune/) with

```
docker image prune
```

On all Docker versions you can delete the untagged images with the longer

```
docker images -q -f dangling=true | xargs docker rmi
```

Comment: Not quite sure this is what the OP is seeing. The images you describe would show as `<none>:<none>`, not the hash. Those look like images that were specifically created / tagged as part of some build process (maybe auto-generated based on git sha? Or some other unique identifier? I'd run `docker image inspect <imageid>` and `docker image history` to figure out where those images came from /  are related to.

Comment: @johnharris85 Yes thank you, I just figured out that the images are built by Jenkins